# highlight cell based on value, mulptie search array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am using VBA to find certain 2 or 3 letter "user id" numbers that live at the end of Purchase order numbers. For instance 123456DWR.

I have about 1500 different "user id" numbers (DWR's) I did not reate the code i am using, but i added 900 or so id's to the search array line.

Currently, this code highlights/colors the entire row the id number is found in. I just need this to highlight the cell it self.

I've tried to make it reference Cells, in stead of Cells.Row but it doesn't work.

Could someone steer me in the right direction? Code Below

```html
Sub Affiliates()
   'This code must be updated as affiliates are added or removed
Dim allRange As Range

Dim searchTerms As Variant
Dim cell As Range, word As Variant

Sheets("UPS").Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
searchTerms = Array("AF2-", "AF3-", "AF4-", "AF5-", "AF6-", "AFP-", "AIP-", "AKB-", "APE-", "ASP-", "AU-", "AU2-", "AU3-", "au4-", "AZ-", "B1-", "BD4-", "BDZ-", "BLS-", "BLT-", "BMK-", "BMP-", "BQ-", "BR2-", "BR3-", "BRI-", "BRT-", "BTU-", "BV-", "BX2-", "BXM-", "BZG-", "CAV-", "CJW-", "CM2-", "CSI-", "DES-", "DGR-", "DXE-", "ED2-", _
"ED3-", "ED4-", "ED5-", "ED6-", "EDA-", "EMV-", "ERR-", "ERS-", "FM2-", "FMP-", "FYI-", "GCK-", "GH-", "GL2-", "GL3-", "GLP-", "GPR-", "GSH-", "HDL-", "HMF-", "HO-", "HW2-", "HWM-", "J33-", "JC4-", "JC5-", "JCG-", "JFG-", "JG-", "JGR-", "JJM-", "JPR-", "JR4-", "JRD-", "JRW-", "JSB-", "JWW-", "KAH-", "KBP-", "KC2-", _
"KCP-", "KM2-", "KMF-", "KN2-", "KN3-", "KNC-", "KP2-", "KPB-", "KRN-", "KRT-", "LKV-", "MB-", "MJP-", "MYG-", "MZE-", "P72-", "PAC-", "PTG-", "PVT-", "RGN-", "S42-", "S44-", "S45-", "S46-", "S48-", "S52-", "S53-", "SA1-", "SA5-", "SAN-", "SD2-", "SD3-", "SD4-", "SD5-", "SD6-", "SD7-", "SD8-", "SD9-", "SHK-", "SKY-", "SMY-", "SN-", "SP-", _
"SPA-", "SQ2-", "SQX-", "SUD-", "SUE-", "SZT-", "TEL-", "TF2-", "TGT-", "THR-", "TMT-", "tpp-", "VN-", "WR-", "WX-", "WX3-", "WYS-", "YM2-", "YM3-", "YM4-", "YM5-", "YMT-", "wdd-""AAA-", "ABT-", "CM3-", "CM5-", "CMG-", "DCD-", "DR9-", "DRB-", "DRW-", "DVW-", "EE-", "EG2-", "EG3-", "EGS-", "EMD-", "EP2-", "EP3-", "EP5-", "EPS-", "EV-", "FAS-", "FL2-", "GM8-", "GM9-", "GMN-", "KR5-", "KR6-", "KR7-", "KRC-", "M33-", "M34-", "M35-", "M36-", "M37-", "M38-", "M39-", "M42-", _
"M43-", "M46-", "M47-", "M48-", "M49-", "MM2-", "MOX-", "MR3-", "MR4-", "MRV-", "MS5-", "MS6-", "MS7-", "MS8-", "MS9-", "MSY-", "MT-", "MUS-", "NM-", "P32-", "PF6-", "PFP-", "PM2-", "PM3-", "PM4-", "PM5-", "PM6-", "PM7-", "PM8-", "PM9-", "PMR-", "RS2-", "RSD-", "RST-", "S62-", "S63-", "SHE-", "SMK-", "SUN-", "SVA-", "Z1-", "Z42-", "ZA5-", "ZA6-", "ZAG-", "ZAH-", "ZDM-", _
"3P-", "AAP-", "AD3-", "AD4-", "AD9-", "ADC-", "ADV-", "AFF-", "AJT-", "ALB-", "AMA-", "AP2-", "AP3-", "APG-", "APM-", "APS-", "ARG-", "ASA-", "AVD-", "AZP-", "BAG-", "BCD-", "BCK-", "BE2-", "BE3-", "BGB-", "BJB-", "BP2-", "BPM-", "BR-", "BTC-", "BTM-", "BUZ-", "BWL-", "C22-", "C23-", "C24-", "CAR-", "CCP-", "CCW-", "CG-", "CGK-", "CLJ-", "CME-", "CP9-", "CPM-", "CPR-", "CPT-", "CPU-", "CRM-", "CRN-", "CT-", "DAV-", "DC-", "DC3-", "DC4-", "DKP-", "DNC-", "DNF-", "DNT-", "DP2-", "DPL-", "DPT-", "DQ-", "DR2-", "DRT-", "E22-", "EI-", "EP-", "FB2-", "FB3-", "FBG-", "FCA-", "FL-", "FLN-", "FNN-", "FPS-", "FVE-", "GA-", "GB2-", "GEE-", "GF2-", "GFS-", "GFY-", "GM-", "GME-", "GN-", "GU2-", "GUS-", _
"HJS-", "JAE-", "JDN-", "JHG-", "JNK-", "JTP-", "JWP-", "JX2-", "KCD-", "KK2-", "KKA-", "KW-", "L22-", "L23-", "l24-", "L9-", "LA5-", "LAX-", "LD-", "LD2-", "LR-", "M44-", "MA2-", "MA5-", "MA6-", "MAJ-", "MAL-", "MD2-", "MD3-", "MDM-", "MK1-", "MKY-", "MM-", "MN-", "MO-", "MP5-", "MPE-", "MRK-", "MTH-", _
"MV-", "MY-", "NA-", "NE2-", "NE3-", "NEP-", "NF-", "NGP-", "NIP-", "NNF-", "NSM-", "OCA-", "OD-", "P62-", "P63-", "PBB-", "PCK-", "PDM-", "PEN-", "PH-", "PHX-", "PLG-", "PMM-", "PMN-", "PNR-", "PPC-", "PPW-", "PSP-", "PST-", "PW3-", "PW5-", "QA-", "QM-", "RAD-", "RAY-", "RE-", "RGK-", "RG5-", "RKT-", "RSW-", "RU-", "RV-", "S27-", "SAM-", "SC2-", "SCG-", "SCH-", "SDC-", "SF2-", "SFL-", "SGE-", "SMA-", "STW-", "TBM-", "TFG-", "THK-", "THY-", "TOG-", "TRC-", "TW2-", "TWE-", "TY2-", "TYB-", "UC-", "UH-", "UP2-", "UP3-", "UPW-", "VB-", "WDB-", "WM-", "WTC-", "WZ-", "XS-", "YN-", "YN2-", "YN3-", "YN4-", "YN5-", "YN6-", "YN7-", "YNG-", "YP-", "YPR-", "ZA2-", "ZAA-", "ZAD-", "STT-", "ef-", "JX-", _
"A2-", "ABP-", "ABS-", "AE-", "AF-", "AJ-", "ALL-", "AM-", "AN2-", "ANS-", "AP-", "APP-", "ASJ-", "ASK-", "ASM-", "ATJ-", "BA2-", "BAA-", "BAM-", "BAS-", "BBE-", "BBP-", "BG-", "BG2-", "BGD-", "BK2-", "BK3-", "BK4-", "BK5-", "BK6-", "BK7-", "BLZ-", "BMG-", "BP-", "BSK-", "BTB-", "BX-", "BYJ-", "CEC-", "CHT-", "CJ2-", "CJR-", "CMB-", "CN-", "COB-", "CPC-", "CPP-", "CTA-", "CWG-", "D22-", "D24-", "D25-", "D26-", "D27-", "D28-", "D29-", "D30-", "D32-", "D33-", "D34-", "D35-", "DAJ-", "DAK-", "DAP-", "DB2-", "DBC-", "DBP-", "DCA-", "DDP-", "DEL-", "DGJ-", "DMJ-", "DP3-", "DPI-", "DRA-", "DS-", "DS2-", "DS3-", "DS4-", "DS5-", "DS6-", "DS7-", "DS8-", "DS9-", "DSN-", "DSP-", "DSR-", "DT2-", "DT3-", _
"DT4-", "DT5-", "DTM-", "EC2-", "ECL-", "EDM-", "ENS-", "ERN-", "ES2-", "ES3-", "es4-", "ESC-", "ESH-", "EZB-", "FDA-", "FI-", "FI2-", "GBL-", "GCR-", "GRR-", "GS-", "GT2-", "GTE-", "HM2-", "HM3-", "HM4-", "HM5-", "HMG-", "HN-", "HNN-", "IA-", "JMS-", "JSY-", "K24-", "K26-", "K27-", "KAU-", "KMK-", "KPN-", "KRK-", "LT-", "MDY-", "MKD-", "MLM-", "MMM-", "MP-", "MR2-", "MR6-", "MRA-", "MRE-", "NAA-", "PA-", "PCS-", "PK2-", "PK3-", "PK4-", "PK5-", "PKG-", "POD-", "PT4-", "PTS-", "RDV-", "RH2-", "RHS-", "RJS-", "SA-", "SBG-", "SEB-", "SJP-", "SL2-", "SLT-", "SQ-", "STC-", "STF-", "SY-", "T99-", "TRY-", "UMT-", "VP-", "VZ-", "VZ1-", "WAG-", "WDM-", "WH-", "YJ-", "STM", _
"A1-", "AMS-", "AN-", "AY2-", "AYW-", "BB-", "BDS-", "BJC-", "BNG-", "BSH-", "BW2-", "BWR-", "BWS-", "CGP-", "CM4-", "CPS-", "CQS-", "CV-", "CWN-", "CY-", "D42-", "D43-", "DPB-", "DTG-", "DTY-", "DV-", "DVD-", "DVE-", "DY2-", "ELR-", "ENX-", "EST-", "FN2-", "FN3-", "FN4-", "FNT-", "FNY-", "FS2-", "FSN-", "GBD-", "GG2-", "GGM-", "GLM-", "GM5-", "GSE-", "HCE-", "HGT-", "HNA-", "HYD-", "IB-", "IE-", "IW-", "J32-", "JBE-", "JEN-", "JLR-", "JLW-", "JN6-", "JN7-", "JN8-", "JNH-", "JV2-", "JVP-", "KA2-", "KBK-", "KNX-", "KPP-", "KPR-", "LC-", "LPE-", "LRE-", "LV2-", "LV3-", "LV4-", "LV5-", "LVL-", "M12-", "M15-", "M19-", "M24-", "M51-", "M52-", "M53-", "M55-", "M57-", "M63-", "M64-", "M68-", "M69-", "M72-", "M73-", "M74-", "M75-", "MCC-", "MCK-", "MHA-", "MJF-", "MKE-", "MMT-", "MP2-", _
"MPN-", "MPT-", "MR5-", "MST-", "MU6-", "MUN-", "NEB-", "NVT-", "NY5-", "PJ2-", "PJM-", "PNY-", "PRV-", "PTM-", "PTN-", "RCG-", "RED-", "REN-", "RH3-", "RN2-", "RND-", "RT2-", "RT3-", "RT4-", "RTC-", "SDM-", "SPP-", "SV2-", "SV3-", "SV4-", "SV5-", "SV6-", "SV7-", "SVN-", "SVS-", "SXT-", "TCB-", "TE5-", "TE6-", "TEE-", "TER-", "TK2-", "TKG-", "TNY-", "TUV-", "VPG-", "VU-", "VW2-", "VWP-", "W25-", "WO-", "WR4-", "WR5-", "WR6-", "WR8-", "WR9-", "WRH-", "WTT-", "Y23-", "YG-", "YK-", "Z22-", "Z23-", "ZAM-", "ZAQ-", "ZAR-", "ZAS-", "ZAU-", "ZFG-", "ZIN-", "ZR2-", "BA-", "BAR-", "BES-", "BLR-", "BS2-", "BSY-", "CD-", "CRT-", "CS-", "CT7-", "CTY-", "CVT-", "CWP-", "CZ-", "DRS-", "DVL-", "EM2-", "EM3-", "EM4-", "EM5-", "EMF-", "EPR-", "EVE-", "FP-", "FSP-", "FST-", "HTT-", "JA5-", "JAC-", "JAN-", "JK2-", "JKH-", _
"BNT-", "DER-", "DWH-", "EL-", "EU-", "FF-", "FM-", "FR-", "FSZ-", "GC-", "GMA-", "GMS-", "HB-", "ISM-", "JAA-", "JBS-", "JD-", "KG-", "KKP-", "KYT-", "LBG-", "LCH-", "LFM-", "LGG-", "M0-", "MBS-", "MC2-", "MCD-", "N41-", "NKS-", "NTR-", "PBD-", "PG-", "PPA-", "PQT-", "PRE-", "PT7-", "PT9-", "PTE-", "PTY-", "RSN-", "SBE-", "SCB-", "SCR-", "T32-", "T33-", "TA-", "TMA-", "TRX-", "TWN-", "UBR-", "UM2-", "UMP-", "WCA-", "XP-", "YBH-", "ZAV-", "JKM-", "JPD-", "JW-", "KA3-", "KA5-", "KAG-", "KB-", "KG4-", "KG5-", "KGP-", "KNS-", "LGW-", "LMN-", "LSG-", "LU2-", "MAE-", "MDG-", "MDN-", "MMP-", "MPM-", "MPV-", "MR-", "MRG-", "N22-", "N23-", "N25-", "N26-", "N28-", "N29-", "N35-", "N36-", "N37-", "N38-", "N39-", "NK2-", "NK3-", "NK8-", "NKD-", "PFA-", "PFU-", "PHM-", "PM-", "PMD-", "PPM-", "PRD-", "PT-", "PV2-", "PV3-", "PV4-", "PVC-", "PW6-", "PWP-", "PX-", "PXZ-", "PZ2-", "PZZ-", "RAV-", "RKY-", "RPC-", "RUF-", "RV2-", "RV3-", "SEG-", "SHM-", _
"SJM-", "SJR-", "SN2-", "SN3-", "SN4-", "SNP-", "SRC-", "T22-", "T23-", "T24-", "TKA-", "TRK-", "TSQ-", "TST-", "W3-", "W5-", "W6-", "WJM-", "WRX-", "X0-", "XM2-", "XM3-", "XM4-", "XPD-", "yd-", "ZAB-", "ZAC-", "ZAE-", "ZAN-", "ZAT-", "LU-", "WY-", "ZL-", "ABN-", "AT-", "ATH-", "AYH-", "BDD-", "BMD-", "BNB-", "BRN-", "BRY-", "BU-", "CCG-", "CFL-", "CKH-", "CXS-", "DJB-", "EAB-", "EJ-", "ETP-", "FNE-", "GB-", "GER-", "GGN-", "GHP-", "GI-", "GR2-", "GR5-", "GR6-", "GR7-", "GR8-", "GRY-", "HCR-", "HN3-", "HNT-", "JBM-", "JEM-", "JFM-", "JKR-", "JNP-", "JS2-", "JU4-", "JU5-", "JU6-", "JU7-", "JU8-", "JU9-", "JYD-", "KE-", "KE2-", "KT2-", "KT3-", "KTE-", "KY2-", "KYN-", _
"LFD-", "LLD-", "LNE-", "LX-", "ME2-", "ME3-", "MEC-", "MRN-", "MY2-", "MYM-", "NE-", "NFN-", "NMK-", "NT2-", "NT3-", "NTW-", "PD2-", "PD3-", "PD4-", "PD5-", "PDT-", "PH2-", "PHS-", "PMC-", "PP2-", "PPB-", "PSY-", "PTA-", "PW2-", "PW4-", "PWA-", "PWD-", "PWH-", "PY2-", "PY3-", "PY4-", "PYS-", "PYV-", "RDG-", "RGP-", "RKP-", "RKX-", "RPP-", "RUS-", "SC-", "SM2-", "SM5-", "SMS-", "SND-", "TEP-", "TKY-", "TUH-", "VPS-", "VST-", "VU2-", "VU3-", "VUE-", "WC-", "WC2-", "WPP-", "WRD-", "YU-")


ReDim rowsToHighlight(0) As String

Set allRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange


For Each cell In allRange
For Each word In searchTerms
If InStr(1, cell, word, vbTextCompare) Then
rowsToHighlight(UBound(rowsToHighlight)) = CStr(cell.Row)
ReDim Preserve rowsToHighlight(UBound(rowsToHighlight) + 1)
End If
Next word
Next cell
On Error Resume Next
ReDim Preserve rowsToHighlight(UBound(rowsToHighlight) - 1)

Dim v As Long
For v = UBound(rowsToHighlight) To LBound(rowsToHighlight) Step -1
Rows(rowsToHighlight(v)).Interior.Color = vbGreen
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your procedure can be improved further as it actually requires heavy maintenance as indicated by:

> I have about 1500 different "user id" numbers (DWR's) I did not reate
>   the code i am using, but i added 900 or so id's to the search array
>   line

```
'This code must be updated as affiliates are added or removed
```

Therefore I suggest to create a table in a separated worksheet then the procedure can automatically get the array of items to search.

Also there is not need to loop thru every cell in the worksheet "UPS" and compare the contents with the items in the list, instead use the `FIND` function.

The code below includes all the above and additionally gives the possibility of highlighting the string found (user id).

```
Sub Affiliates()
Rem Use a table to keep the list of affiliates instead of "Hard Codding" it (see Set Users ID List below)
Const kCol As Byte = 3 'Indicates the column containing the User Id's List
Dim WshSrc As Worksheet, WshTrg As Worksheet
Dim aUsrIdLst As Variant, vUsrId As Variant
Dim rFound As Range, sFound1st As String
Dim bPos As Byte

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Rem Set Worksheets
    Set WshSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UserIds")
    Set WshTrg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UPS")

    Rem Set Users ID List
    With WshSrc
        aUsrIdLst = .Cells(1, kCol).Resize(fLastRow_byCol(.Columns(kCol))).Value2
        aUsrIdLst = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(aUsrIdLst)
    End With

    Rem To Clear prior formatting - Uncomment if needed
    Rem watch out for prior formatting of all other cells!
    Rem WshTrg.UsedRange.Style = "Normal"

    With WshTrg.UsedRange
        For Each vUsrId In aUsrIdLst
            Set rFound = .Find( _
                What:=vUsrId, After:=.Cells(1), _
                LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not (rFound Is Nothing) Then
                sFound1st = rFound.Address
                Do
                    With rFound
                        bPos = InStr(rFound, vUsrId)
                        Rem Fill Interior and String Found
                        .Interior.Color = vbGreen
                        With .Characters(Start:=bPos, Length:=Len(vUsrId)).Font
                            .Bold = 1
                            .Color = RGB(55, 86, 35)
                    End With: End With
                    Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
                Loop While Not (rFound Is Nothing) And rFound.Address <> sFound1st

    End If: Next: End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic    'update as required

End Sub


Function fLastRow_byCol(ColTrg As Range) As Long
Rem ===============================================================================
    On Error Resume Next
    fLastRow_byCol = ColTrg.Find(What:="*", _
        After:=ColTrg.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: EEM, 
This is amazing! Thank you so much! This was really where  i wanted to go with this. So much faster, and now i can use that sheet as a depository for those ID codes when they are updated. Epic!!

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need in the macro (in addition to the declarations and the definition of searchTerms, but look also into conditional formatting

```
Set allRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

For Each cell In allRange
    For Each word In searchTerms
        If InStr(1, cell, word, vbTextCompare) Then cell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    Next word
Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed your list to a comma separated string and split it for use. Removed allRange, rowHighloght array, and other unnecessary stuff.

Make sure you exit a long check sequence like this when a match is made using `Exit For`. You don't need the sheet to be active to reference it. I left the `.Activate` at the end in case you wanted the code to send you there when it's done, but it can just as easily be removed.

```
Sub Affiliates()
   'This code must be updated as affiliates are added or removed
  Dim searchTerms As Variant
  Dim cell As Range, word As Variant

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlManual
  searchTerms = "AF2-,AF3-,AF4-,AF5-,AF6-,AFP-,AIP-,AKB-,APE-,ASP-,AU-,AU2-,AU3-,au4-,AZ-,B1-,BD4-,BDZ-,BLS-,BLT-,BMK-,BMP-,BQ-,BR2-,BR3-,BRI-,BRT-,BTU-,BV-,BX2-,BXM-,BZG-,CAV-,CJW-,CM2-,CSI-,DES-,DGR-,DXE-,ED2-," & _
"ED3-,ED4-,ED5-,ED6-,EDA-,EMV-,ERR-,ERS-,FM2-,FMP-,FYI-,GCK-,GH-,GL2-,GL3-,GLP-,GPR-,GSH-,HDL-,HMF-,HO-,HW2-,HWM-,J33-,JC4-,JC5-,JCG-,JFG-,JG-,JGR-,JJM-,JPR-,JR4-,JRD-,JRW-,JSB-,JWW-,KAH-,KBP-,KC2-," & _
"KCP-,KM2-,KMF-,KN2-,KN3-,KNC-,KP2-,KPB-,KRN-,KRT-,LKV-,MB-,MJP-,MYG-,MZE-,P72-,PAC-,PTG-,PVT-,RGN-,S42-,S44-,S45-,S46-,S48-,S52-,S53-,SA1-,SA5-,SAN-,SD2-,SD3-,SD4-,SD5-,SD6-,SD7-,SD8-,SD9-,SHK-,SKY-,SMY-,SN-,SP-," & _
"SPA-,SQ2-,SQX-,SUD-,SUE-,SZT-,TEL-,TF2-,TGT-,THR-,TMT-,tpp-,VN-,WR-,WX-,WX3-,WYS-,YM2-,YM3-,YM4-,YM5-,YMT-,wdd-,AAA-,ABT-,CM3-,CM5-,CMG-,DCD-,DR9-,DRB-,DRW-,DVW-,EE-,EG2-,EG3-,EGS-,EMD-,EP2-,EP3-,EP5-,EPS-,EV-,FAS-,FL2-,GM8-,GM9-,GMN-,KR5-,KR6-,KR7-,KRC-,M33-,M34-,M35-,M36-,M37-,M38-,M39-,M42-," & _
"M43-,M46-,M47-,M48-,M49-,MM2-,MOX-,MR3-,MR4-,MRV-,MS5-,MS6-,MS7-,MS8-,MS9-,MSY-,MT-,MUS-,NM-,P32-,PF6-,PFP-,PM2-,PM3-,PM4-,PM5-,PM6-,PM7-,PM8-,PM9-,PMR-,RS2-,RSD-,RST-,S62-,S63-,SHE-,SMK-,SUN-,SVA-,Z1-,Z42-,ZA5-,ZA6-,ZAG-,ZAH-,ZDM-," & _
"3P-,AAP-,AD3-,AD4-,AD9-,ADC-,ADV-,AFF-,AJT-,ALB-,AMA-,AP2-,AP3-,APG-,APM-,APS-,ARG-,ASA-,AVD-,AZP-,BAG-,BCD-,BCK-,BE2-,BE3-,BGB-,BJB-,BP2-,BPM-,BR-,BTC-,BTM-,BUZ-,BWL-,C22-,C23-,C24-,CAR-,CCP-,CCW-,CG-,CGK-,CLJ-,CME-,CP9-,CPM-,CPR-,CPT-,CPU-,CRM-,CRN-,CT-,DAV-,DC-,DC3-,DC4-,DKP-,DNC-,DNF-,DNT-,DP2-,DPL-,DPT-,DQ-,DR2-,DRT-,E22-,EI-,EP-,FB2-,FB3-,FBG-,FCA-,FL-,FLN-,FNN-,FPS-,FVE-,GA-,GB2-,GEE-,GF2-,GFS-,GFY-,GM-,GME-,GN-,GU2-,GUS-," & _
"HJS-,JAE-,JDN-,JHG-,JNK-,JTP-,JWP-,JX2-,KCD-,KK2-,KKA-,KW-,L22-,L23-,l24-,L9-,LA5-,LAX-,LD-,LD2-,LR-,M44-,MA2-,MA5-,MA6-,MAJ-,MAL-,MD2-,MD3-,MDM-,MK1-,MKY-,MM-,MN-,MO-,MP5-,MPE-,MRK-,MTH-," & _
"MV-,MY-,NA-,NE2-,NE3-,NEP-,NF-,NGP-,NIP-,NNF-,NSM-,OCA-,OD-,P62-,P63-,PBB-,PCK-,PDM-,PEN-,PH-,PHX-,PLG-,PMM-,PMN-,PNR-,PPC-,PPW-,PSP-,PST-,PW3-,PW5-,QA-,QM-,RAD-,RAY-,RE-,RGK-,RG5-,RKT-,RSW-,RU-,RV-,S27-,SAM-,SC2-,SCG-,SCH-,SDC-,SF2-,SFL-,SGE-,SMA-,STW-,TBM-,TFG-,THK-,THY-,TOG-,TRC-,TW2-,TWE-,TY2-,TYB-,UC-,UH-,UP2-,UP3-,UPW-,VB-,WDB-,WM-,WTC-,WZ-,XS-,YN-,YN2-,YN3-,YN4-,YN5-,YN6-,YN7-,YNG-,YP-,YPR-,ZA2-,ZAA-,ZAD-,STT-,ef-,JX-," & _
"A2-,ABP-,ABS-,AE-,AF-,AJ-,ALL-,AM-,AN2-,ANS-,AP-,APP-,ASJ-,ASK-,ASM-,ATJ-,BA2-,BAA-,BAM-,BAS-,BBE-,BBP-,BG-,BG2-,BGD-,BK2-,BK3-,BK4-,BK5-,BK6-,BK7-,BLZ-,BMG-,BP-,BSK-,BTB-,BX-,BYJ-,CEC-,CHT-,CJ2-,CJR-,CMB-,CN-,COB-,CPC-,CPP-,CTA-,CWG-,D22-,D24-,D25-,D26-,D27-,D28-,D29-,D30-,D32-,D33-,D34-,D35-,DAJ-,DAK-,DAP-,DB2-,DBC-,DBP-,DCA-,DDP-,DEL-,DGJ-,DMJ-,DP3-,DPI-,DRA-,DS-,DS2-,DS3-,DS4-,DS5-,DS6-,DS7-,DS8-,DS9-,DSN-,DSP-,DSR-,DT2-,DT3-," & _
"DT4-,DT5-,DTM-,EC2-,ECL-,EDM-,ENS-,ERN-,ES2-,ES3-,es4-,ESC-,ESH-,EZB-,FDA-,FI-,FI2-,GBL-,GCR-,GRR-,GS-,GT2-,GTE-,HM2-,HM3-,HM4-,HM5-,HMG-,HN-,HNN-,IA-,JMS-,JSY-,K24-,K26-,K27-,KAU-,KMK-,KPN-,KRK-,LT-,MDY-,MKD-,MLM-,MMM-,MP-,MR2-,MR6-,MRA-,MRE-,NAA-,PA-,PCS-,PK2-,PK3-,PK4-,PK5-,PKG-,POD-,PT4-,PTS-,RDV-,RH2-,RHS-,RJS-,SA-,SBG-,SEB-,SJP-,SL2-,SLT-,SQ-,STC-,STF-,SY-,T99-,TRY-,UMT-,VP-,VZ-,VZ1-,WAG-,WDM-,WH-,YJ-,STM," & _
"A1-,AMS-,AN-,AY2-,AYW-,BB-,BDS-,BJC-,BNG-,BSH-,BW2-,BWR-,BWS-,CGP-,CM4-,CPS-,CQS-,CV-,CWN-,CY-,D42-,D43-,DPB-,DTG-,DTY-,DV-,DVD-,DVE-,DY2-,ELR-,ENX-,EST-,FN2-,FN3-,FN4-,FNT-,FNY-,FS2-,FSN-,GBD-,GG2-,GGM-,GLM-,GM5-,GSE-,HCE-,HGT-,HNA-,HYD-,IB-,IE-,IW-,J32-,JBE-,JEN-,JLR-,JLW-,JN6-,JN7-,JN8-,JNH-,JV2-,JVP-,KA2-,KBK-,KNX-,KPP-,KPR-,LC-,LPE-,LRE-,LV2-,LV3-,LV4-,LV5-,LVL-,M12-,M15-,M19-,M24-,M51-,M52-,M53-,M55-,M57-,M63-,M64-,M68-,M69-,M72-,M73-,M74-,M75-,MCC-,MCK-,MHA-,MJF-,MKE-,MMT-,MP2-," & _
"MPN-,MPT-,MR5-,MST-,MU6-,MUN-,NEB-,NVT-,NY5-,PJ2-,PJM-,PNY-,PRV-,PTM-,PTN-,RCG-,RED-,REN-,RH3-,RN2-,RND-,RT2-,RT3-,RT4-,RTC-,SDM-,SPP-,SV2-,SV3-,SV4-,SV5-,SV6-,SV7-,SVN-,SVS-,SXT-,TCB-,TE5-,TE6-,TEE-,TER-,TK2-,TKG-,TNY-,TUV-,VPG-,VU-,VW2-,VWP-,W25-,WO-,WR4-,WR5-,WR6-,WR8-,WR9-,WRH-,WTT-,Y23-,YG-,YK-,Z22-,Z23-,ZAM-,ZAQ-,ZAR-,ZAS-,ZAU-,ZFG-,ZIN-,ZR2-,BA-,BAR-,BES-,BLR-,BS2-,BSY-,CD-,CRT-,CS-,CT7-,CTY-,CVT-,CWP-,CZ-,DRS-,DVL-,EM2-,EM3-,EM4-,EM5-,EMF-,EPR-,EVE-,FP-,FSP-,FST-,HTT-,JA5-,JAC-,JAN-,JK2-,JKH-," & _
"BNT-,DER-,DWH-,EL-,EU-,FF-,FM-,FR-,FSZ-,GC-,GMA-,GMS-,HB-,ISM-,JAA-,JBS-,JD-,KG-,KKP-,KYT-,LBG-,LCH-,LFM-,LGG-,M0-,MBS-,MC2-,MCD-,N41-,NKS-,NTR-,PBD-,PG-,PPA-,PQT-,PRE-,PT7-,PT9-,PTE-,PTY-,RSN-,SBE-,SCB-,SCR-,T32-,T33-,TA-,TMA-,TRX-,TWN-,UBR-,UM2-,UMP-,WCA-,XP-,YBH-,ZAV-,JKM-,JPD-,JW-,KA3-,KA5-,KAG-,KB-,KG4-,KG5-,KGP-,KNS-,LGW-,LMN-,LSG-,LU2-,MAE-,MDG-,MDN-,MMP-,MPM-,MPV-,MR-,MRG-,N22-,N23-,N25-,N26-,N28-,N29-,N35-,N36-,N37-,N38-,N39-,NK2-,NK3-,NK8-,NKD-,PFA-,PFU-,PHM-,PM-,PMD-,PPM-,PRD-,PT-,PV2-,PV3-,PV4-,PVC-,PW6-,PWP-,PX-,PXZ-,PZ2-,PZZ-,RAV-,RKY-,RPC-,RUF-,RV2-,RV3-,SEG-,SHM-," & _
"SJM-,SJR-,SN2-,SN3-,SN4-,SNP-,SRC-,T22-,T23-,T24-,TKA-,TRK-,TSQ-,TST-,W3-,W5-,W6-,WJM-,WRX-,X0-,XM2-,XM3-,XM4-,XPD-,yd-,ZAB-,ZAC-,ZAE-,ZAN-,ZAT-,LU-,WY-,ZL-,ABN-,AT-,ATH-,AYH-,BDD-,BMD-,BNB-,BRN-,BRY-,BU-,CCG-,CFL-,CKH-,CXS-,DJB-,EAB-,EJ-,ETP-,FNE-,GB-,GER-,GGN-,GHP-,GI-,GR2-,GR5-,GR6-,GR7-,GR8-,GRY-,HCR-,HN3-,HNT-,JBM-,JEM-,JFM-,JKR-,JNP-,JS2-,JU4-,JU5-,JU6-,JU7-,JU8-,JU9-,JYD-,KE-,KE2-,KT2-,KT3-,KTE-,KY2-,KYN-," & _
"LFD-,LLD-,LNE-,LX-,ME2-,ME3-,MEC-,MRN-,MY2-,MYM-,NE-,NFN-,NMK-,NT2-,NT3-,NTW-,PD2-,PD3-,PD4-,PD5-,PDT-,PH2-,PHS-,PMC-,PP2-,PPB-,PSY-,PTA-,PW2-,PW4-,PWA-,PWD-,PWH-,PY2-,PY3-,PY4-,PYS-,PYV-,RDG-,RGP-,RKP-,RKX-,RPP-,RUS-,SC-,SM2-,SM5-,SMS-,SND-,TEP-,TKY-,TUH-,VPS-,VST-,VU2-,VU3-,VUE-,WC-,WC2-,WPP-,WRD-,YU-"
  searchTerms = Split(searchTerms, ",")

  For Each cell In Sheets("UPS").UsedRange
    For Each word In searchTerms
        If InStr(cell, word) > 0 Then
            cell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
            Exit For
        End If
    Next word
  Next cell

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Sheets("UPS").Activate
End Sub
```